# human_attribute_name and translation files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization

I am running a site w/ English and Spanish translation files, with the English as the default.

Using translations such as:

```
en:
  tenants:
    about: "About"
```

to

```
es:
  tenants:
    about: "Acera"
```

Using

```
t "tenants.about"
```

Works without issue and reads properly from either the en.yml and es.yml files when appropriate.

However, when trying to use the human_attribute_name property to pull model attributes from another section of the spanish es.yml file, the values are not being read.

So something like

```
Job.human_attribute_name(:title)
```

Returns "title" instead of "Título".

The portion of the same es.yml file with the humanized attributes is as follows:

```
 es:
  tenants:
    about: "Acerca"
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      job:
        title: "Título de la oferta de trabajo"
        location: "Localización de la oferta de trabajo"
        job_type: "Tipo de trabajo"
        description: "Descripción"
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Wow - super annoying.

This was at the bottom of the long es.yml translation file from github: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails%2Flocale

```
# remove these aliases after 'activemodel' and 'activerecord' namespaces are removed from 
Rails repository
  activemodel:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
  activerecord:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
```

Which was overriding my activerecord: declaration at the top of the file.

Not the best location considering it's a 200+ line file, but shame on me for not reading the whole thing.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I think the 'es:' is missing, or the indentation is not correct. The `"` are not necessary :

```
es: 
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      job:
        title: Título
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, but i've added the full es.yml to help clarify