# translating activerecord model attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale

I'm trying to translate my model attributes when form errors are shown. The error itself is translated correctly, however, the attribute with the error is not.

in my nb.yml locale I have written:

```
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      book:
        price: "pris"
```

Example output: Price er for kort (minimum 0 tegn)

Am using this locale: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/nb.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed two things that could be the cause of your issue:

1) From [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), you should add the id of the language before active record (I don't know if you have it or not...) like this:

```
nb:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      book:
        price: "Pris"
```

2) Did you remove the aliases after line 201 from `nb.yml` from [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/nb.yml)?

See [this issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685401/human-attribute-name-and-translation-files-in-rails).

Hope this helps!